# javascript convert currency to thousands

Tags: javascript, currency

I have a decimal number**(28045.124578)** and i want it to be converted so that it will show in thousand currency format($28.0K) using javascript.

I am using this script tp convert but this doesn't help

```
function kFormatter(num) {
num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
if (isNaN(num))
{
    num = "0";
}
num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
cents = num % 10;
num = Math.floor(num / 100000).toString();
//console.log('num=', num/1000);
if (cents < 10)
{
    cents = "0" + cents;
}
for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
{
    num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + ',' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
}

return num + '.' + cents;
```

}

but this doesn't help. Please suggest.

Comment: http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/

Comment: no js libraries please!!! I want a custom function to do so.

Comment: Could you be more specific about expected results? For the simplest solution `Math.round(num / 100) / 10;` would give you result

Answer (score 0):

You can use round to get the nearest whole number.

```
function kformatter(num){
    var newvalue =  Math.round(num/100);
    return newvalue?(newvalue/10)+"K":num;
}
```